# ElasticSearch map clustering that final clusters are not bound to the geohash (or geotile grid) grid

Tags: elasticsearch, mapbox-gl-js, opensearch

I am developing an interactive map and my technology stack includes NodeJS, Angular, MapBox, and **ElasticSearch**. My application is a complex data aggregator, and I am trying to cluster my data on the map **using ElasticSearch**.

To understand my problem, let me briefly describe the situation. In ElasticSearch, users are stored as documents, and each user has a location field, which is a `nested` type (meaning that a user can have multiple locations).

On the map, I want to display all user locations along with the number of users in each location. For example, if a user has locations in both Brazil and Italy, their `doc_count` should be included in both Brazil and Italy.

Here is where the clustering problem arises. To maintain the correct `doc_count` for each location, I cannot use any client-side clustering libraries (such as SuperCluster), as they would not be able to accurately calculate the `doc_count` if a person has multiple locations. For example, if a person has locations in both Switzerland and France, and the map is zoomed out, these two countries would merge into one cluster, which would not have the correct `doc_count` value.

Therefore, I can only use the capabilities of ElasticSearch itself. My choice was to use the `geo_tile` aggregation with a nested `geo_centroid` aggregation, which solved the `doc_count` problem and always showed the correct values. However, because `geo_tile` is not a flexible tool, points on the map became too close together (for example, points that exist on the boundary of two tiles).

I started looking for a solution that would allow for more flexible clustering without being tied to tiles or a grid. I found a plugin (https://github.com/opendatasoft/elasticsearch-aggregation-geoclustering) that did exactly what I needed (especially the ability to specify a radius), but it hasn't been updated in a long time and isn't officially supported. This would be a big bottleneck if I installed it on my project.

Can anyone recommend a ready-made solution to my problem? Perhaps a supported plugin or a solution using the already established tools in ElasticSearch?

Comment: How about using H3 [hex bins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohexgrid-aggregation.html)?

Comment: @Val, Thanks for the answer! Haven't seen this type of aggregation since I'm using an older version of elastic. Will need to test and potentially consider upgrading, but this can be an expensive task, thanks for the reply! Ii will start investing this question
and would be grateful if there are any other options.

Comment: You can also generate the H3s externally and store them as an object of 16 H3 hashes (one h3 per zoom level) inside your documents, then you can simply use a terms aggregation on the appropriate H3 field. Works like a charm, I've been doing this way before H3 were supported in Elasticsearch, I also have a plugin with an ingest pipeline processor that helps you generate those H3s at indexing time, but it is still private for now. I'll make it public eventually.

Comment: @Val,  I updated my elastic client to the correct version. it now supports geohex aggregations. but I see that even with the value of the field precision, the clusters are too close to each other.

Comment: Can you confirm you also updated your cluster version because otherwise that wouldn't work

Comment: @Val, oh sorry, not client, I locally up Open Search cluster with the 2.5.0 version ([aws open search support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/03/amazon-opensearch-service-opensearch-version-2-5/) this version support geohex aggregaion )and use "@elastic/elasticsearch": "7.10.0", like client

Comment: You should use the Opensearch client if you are running an Opensearch cluster. It's not advised to mix the ES client with the OS server.

Comment: @Val, I changed my client and it didn't give me desire result. If the cluster is located near the border and the second cluster is also near the border, then they do not merge and are nearby, and due to the size of the pin on the map, it looks like they lie on top of each other. Maybe there is some other way? (Looks like the plan as I did in the plugin, to which I left a link in the question).

Comment: There was also an idea to return IDs of documents and then merge based on IDs already using a super cluster, but even so it will not be possible to do this in an optimized way, since an error occurs too many bucket exception

Comment: It seems that it is possible to use geodistance aggregation in conjunction with something to also combine clusters that were received from geotile. But I still haven't found a way to do it.